# How to use onUpdated and onActivated simultanously?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my extension i have in `background.js` an `onUpdated` listener, which pulls some data with `XHR` and `XPath` into `badgeText`.

But, if i activated an old tab without to do anything in it, just click on its tab in the tab bar, `onUpdated` isn't fired and i have in the badge data from the previously opened tab.

The similar happens with old tabs, which were `discarded`. If i click on their tabs in the tab bar (again, without to do anything) `onUpdated` isn't fired.

It seems to be, that `onUpdated` doesn't covers an activation of the tab.

How can i use simultanously `onUpdated` and `onActivated` to cover events i described? Or is there any other approach to catch an event of the tab, where i just click on the tab in the tab bar?

I want to bind my `XHR` and `setBadgeText` action to both of `onUpdated` and `onActivated`, so simple clicking on the tab in the tab bar becomes a trigger too. In other case i should force users of my extension to manually refresh pages to get new data.

**PS**: this is `background.js`

```
var currentDomain = "";
var currentHost = "";
var currentFullpath = "";
var currentUrl = "";
var currentFolder = "";
var badgeText = "";

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active' : true, 'currentWindow': true}, function(tabs){
        if( ! (tabs.length == 0)){
          let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
          currentHost = newUrl.host;
          currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
          currentFullpath = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));
          currentFolder = currentUrl.split("/");
          parsed = psl.parse(currentHost);
          currentDomain = parsed.domain;



  chrome.storage.sync.get('savedApi', ({savedApi}) => {

console.log("savedApi: "+savedApi);

if(savedApi == null)
          savedApi = 'de';
if(currentDomain == null)
          return false; 
if(currentUrl == null)
          return false; 

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var protocol = "https://";
        var middle = ".myservice.com/seo/__loadModule/domain/"
        var end = "/mobile/1/_action/_data_visindex_normal/";

console.log("xhr: "+xhr);

        xhr.open("GET", protocol+savedApi+middle+currentDomain+end, true);

        xhr.responseType='document';



         xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

          if (this.readyState == 4) { 



            function getElementByXpath(path) {
            return xhr.response.evaluate(path, xhr.response, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
            }

            badgeText = getElementByXpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='data']/span[@class='value']/text())");

console.log("newUrl: "+newUrl);
console.log("currentHost: "+currentHost);
console.log("currentUrl: "+currentUrl);
console.log("currentFullpath: "+currentFullpath);
console.log("currentFolder: "+currentFolder);
console.log("currentDomain: "+currentDomain);

            chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title: "Mobile visibility of "+currentDomain+" is "+ String(badgeText)});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(badgeText)});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: '#1d2554' });


           }
        } 
        xhr.send();
      })
      }
    })
   })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both listeners and one common function that does the job. To avoid double invocation set tabId's "processing" state in a global object, clear it when done.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.url) run(tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(info => {
  chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, run);
});

const processingTabId = {};

function run(tab) {
  if (processingTabId[tab.id]) return;
  processingTabId[tab.id] = true;

  let newUrl = new URL(tab.url);
  currentHost = newUrl.host;
  currentUrl = tab.url;

  doSomeAsyncStuff(() => {
    //................................
    // when all done:
    delete processingTabId[tab.id];
  });
}
```

Note there's no need for chrome.tabs.query because onUpdated already gives you the `tab` object. Also not only active tab get updates, the inactive ones do too. And not just URLs are reported: also favicon, title, muted state, and many other things.

Comment: Ah, thats the way to use them both! ok, i'll go to test it. Thank you! BTW. why `delete processingTabId`?

Comment: Could you explain please, what should be inside of `doSomeAsyncStuff(() => {`? I tried to place the whole `XHR` part into it, but this leads me to `doSomeAsyncStuff is not defined`...

Comment: There's no such thing as doSomeAsyncStuff, it's an imaginary substitute name for any code you may have. I added it just to make it more obvious when to perform `delete` operation.

Comment: Does it mean, `delete` should be done after `xhr.send();` or after `xhr.onreadystatechange`?

Comment: It should be inside the callback because it runs later, this is how asynchronous code works. For example right after you set the icon.

Comment: If i open an URL in a background tab, like with middle mouse click, the textBadge in the current tab changes to those from the site, which is opened in the background tab - and even a manual refresh of the current tab doesn't help to get correct data into it. I'm afraid, `onUpdated` fires for the background tab too...

Comment: onUpdated fires for all tabs, yes. You need to specify tabId in each browserAction method you call to set the badge, title, and so on. See the documentation.

Comment: Would it work too, if onUpdate will be binded to onHighlighted, so onUpdated fires only if the tab is visible?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Like `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
 chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(
   function(highlightInfo) {
     chrome.tabs.get(highlightInfo.tabIds[0], function(tab) {
        if (changeInfo.url == tab.url) run(tab);
    })
  })
})`

Comment: I don't think it'd be useful because you would be adding a listener for every tab update but how would you unregister it? They would be all competing with each other. Listeners should be usually declared one time in the global scope. I don't understand what you want to achieve here so I can't help. Open a new question because this is not related to this answer.