# Correct way to hook Chrome extension background script message handler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a custom dev-tools panel extension with the background script that connects panel and page  together. It worked great with only one tab but when I opened a second or third tab, I got duplicated messages because the runtime.onMessage handler was duplicated. To fix this I modified the code to check if the handler was already hooked but I've still got problems.

background.js

```
(function () {
  var tabCount = 0;
  var devPanelPorts = {};

    let chromeMessageHandler = function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log('background message listener', sender.tab.id, sender, request);
      if (sender.tab) {
        var tabId = sender.tab.id;
        if (tabId in devPanelPorts) {
          devPanelPorts[tabId].postMessage(request);  //definition removed here for simplicity
      }
      return true;
    }

    if (!chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(chromeMessageHandler)) {   //On the second call this is still true
      console.log("hook background message listener");
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(chromeMessageHandler);
      tabCount++;
      console.log(chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(chromeMessageHandler)); //returns true
    }
    ...
})();
```

chromeMessageHandler is hooked correctly the first time, but the second time chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(chromeMessageHandler) is still false. If I move chromeMessageHandler to a var outside of the IFFE, it looks like it works. I'd prefer to have it in the IFFE but what I don't get is tabCount increments correctly, remembering the correct value for the second and third call. Why does tabCount refer to the same variable but chromeMessageHandler doesn't seem to?

What is the correct way to write this part of the extension background script?

Comment: Every time this code runs it makes a new function object in chromeMessageHandler so it'll never be found by hasListener. You can use hasListeners() or redesign the entire workflow to always use just one listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was hoping that you would respond, thanks for that. You have some extensions on GreasyFork, is there one there which you could recommend as an example?

Comment: GF lists only userscripts, there are no extensions. I didn't write devtools extensions anyway.

Comment: Yeah I realised it was only scripts after posting the comment. I moved chromeMessageHandler outside of the IIFE and hasListener, seems to work fine. I check how many tabs are using it and if 0 I unhook it. Would you put the handler outside the IIFE or use hasListeners?

Comment: I would register onMessage listener just once. The dynamic data for the listener would be handled in a some kind of object/Map/array declared in the common/global scope. Examples: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61600254), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60546356).